# CORS error in .then clause of HTTP request

Tags: javascript, http, cors, vue.js

So I am using this.router to change pages in my client application (the application is communicating with a server I build handling authentication). Unfortunately I am met with a CORS error in my application when I do router.push inside the .then clause. However when I use router.push outside the .then clause I receive no errors. Any idea what is causing this?

```
signup: function () {


  this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/signup?username='+this.username+'&password='+this.password+'&password2='+this.password2)

    .then(response => {
        if(response.body== "success"){
          this.pass_or_fail=response.body;         
        // this.$router.push({name:'landing-page'}); this Gives me a CORS error        
        }
    })
//  this.$router.push({name:'landing-page'}); this works fine

}
```

Comment: Can you attach the whole CORS error message?

Comment: What is the exact error message? If it's a cross-domain access error I have a cool solution for you.

Comment: I solved it I just used the CORS module for express

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might not actually be a CORS issue. `this` inside the `.then` callback is bound to the callback, and not to the Vue instance.

To test this idea, on the first line of the signup function, do this...

```
signup: function () {
  const vm = this
  ...
```

and then inside the callback use `vm` instead of `this`...

```
.then(response => {
  ...
  vm.$router.push(...)
```

If that works, then make sure to also do `vm.pass_or_fail=response.body`

Comment: He is using arrow functions. You sure that this is the case? Not sure myself here.

Comment: Yeah with the arrow functions do not create their own context for this